# Formatting individual words in textboxes in Microstrategy

Tags: textbox, richtextbox, microstrategy

Is there a way to format some of the words in a textbox differently in Microstrategy?

Answer (score 0):

I never managed to do it, so I end up either putting several textboxes, or replacing it with a HTML container where I can format text the way I want.

Comment: Thanks! I want the text fields to be writable. I want the users to be able to enter text in them. Is it possible to achieve it using html containers?

Comment: Yes, just put some forms elements